# Script to list only files of type ASCII text in the current directory?

Tags: shell-script, files, mime-types

How to write a shell script which searches the current UNIX directory and returns the names of all files of type ASCII text?

Comment: The script you've shown above doesn't seem to relate to the question at all. That's odd.

Answer (score 13):

The best of 2 worlds: Avoids the use of the useless `xargs`, and speeds things up, since the `+` triggers parallel invocation.

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep ASCII
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to add, that this is a `gnu-find` extension. Most of the time I forget about that.

Comment: great, congrats

Comment: @user unknown: "+"' isn't a gnu-find extension. It was first introduced by SVR4 find then adopted by the POSIX standard and later included by Gnu find. Every current find implementation is very likely to implement it.

Comment: Thanks @jiliagre, my horizon is to tall, I just know a little bit about about Linux, and enjoy to learn new facts.

Answer (score 2):

Exec 'file' on all the files in the current directoy, and then grep for 'ASCII':

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec file {} \; | grep ASCII
```

Comment: How portable is `grep ASCII`? I remember that once I had problems because the output of `file` is not exactly the same on all systems but I don't recall if it was related with ASCII files.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep ASCII`

On CentOS 5, ASCII can mean a lot of things such as "ASCII C++ program text", "ASCII English text", and "ASCII text" so you might need to narrow it down more.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just the current directory, no need for `find`.

Just try `file * .* | fgrep ASCII`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you get directory name as the argument ($1), then,

```
ls $1 | while read name
    do
        # "file" returns file type
        file $1/$name | grep -i 'ascii' &> /dev/null

        # $? gives exit status of previous command
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            # $1/$name is your ascii file, process it here...
        fi
    done
```